# Access table field on creating a trigger postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

How can I access table field on creating a trigger?

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON foo
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc(foo.field);//here goes the parameter
```

Comment: [Cross-posted to dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64374/access-table-field-on-creating-a-trigger-postgresql/64389#64389), where I've answered.

Answer (score 3):

Trigger's parameter is a string always - so you cannot use a SQL identifier there. But you can use string as name and use dynamic SQL for access to requested field:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(a int, b int);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo_update_trg()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE t text;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('SELECT $1.%I', TG_ARGV[0]) INTO t USING old; 
  RAISE NOTICE 'original value of "%" is "%"', TG_ARGV[0], t;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$function$

CREATE TRIGGER foo_update_trigger_a AFTER UPDATE ON foo FOR EACH ROW 
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo_update_trg('a');
CREATE TRIGGER foo_update_trigger_b AFTER UPDATE ON foo FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo_update_trg('b');

INSERT INTO foo VALUES(10,20);
UPDATE foo SET a = 20, b = 40;
```

The important is line

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT $1.%I', TG_ARGV[0]) INTO t USING old;
```

It is usage of dynamic SQL (plpgsql statement EXECUTE) and string formatting function (function format). First we prepare a string "SELECT $1.a" ~ that is a reference to field "a" of first dynamic SQL parameter, and we eval this string as query - parameter for this query is passed via USING clause.